# Fetch Specific Text area using Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom, scrape

```
<font class="detDesc">Uploaded <b>2015-02-21 19:51:38</b>, 
 Size (7.37 MB), ULed by 
 <a class="detDesc" href="/user/FirstUploads/"
 title="Browse FirstUploads">FirstUploads</a>
</font>
```

hello am new to Simple HTML DOM

i want to scrape this dynamic size area -> (7.37 MB) only..

am using this code..

```
<?php 
 include 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
 $html = file_get_html('http://some site.com/');

 foreach($html->find('font[class=detDesc] b') as $size2) 
 { 
 $size[]=  $mysqli->real_escape_string(trim($size2->plaintext)); 
 echo $size2->plaintext.'<br>';
 } 
?>
```

but its giving me this -> (2015-02-21 19:51:38)..

as i want only ->  (7.37 MB)

any suggestions.. ?

Comment: is it not your selector: `font[class=detDesc] b` is only getting the bold tag, you either need to wrap your size and then get that or just use `font[class=detDesc]` and then do a split on `Size` or `,`

Comment: thanks @Pete can i have the code example for your suggestion? am sorry am new to Simple HTML DOM.

Comment: Been a while since I've done php but this may help: http://jsfiddle.net/yuL8c11x/

Comment: I use this code.. 

foreach($html->find('font[class=detDesc]') as $size2) 
 { 
     $size[]=  explode(",", trim($size2->plaintext)); 
     $size = substr($size[1], 5, -1); 
  echo $size2->plaintext.'<br>';
}

but it gives me -> Uploaded <b>2015-02-21 19:51:38, 
 Size 7.37 MB, ULed by

as i only need  7.37MB
or try this link
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/yuL8c11x/2/)

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/yuL8c11x/3/

Comment: it gives me an error..

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\tpb.php on line 39

Warning: substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in D:\tpb.php on line 39

Comment: try removing the `[]` from `$sizes[] = explode`

Comment: ok its working but its missing the last alphabet from the size value,

eg: 374.34 Mi , 1.04 Gi, 821.34 Ki

they should be like 374.34 MiB, 1.04 GiB, 821.34 KiB

Comment: ok its done.. i have removed the -1 and change it to..

$size = substr($sizes[1], 5);

Thanks alot.. @Pete

Comment: Cool, the -1 was for the end bracket before the next comma, but looks as if your data doesn't have that

Comment: yes i got it already.. but am facing only 1 problem now..
i was using array to store that data into sql table.. but in this code we have removed the array [].. so this size part only echoing but not storing into database..  

`$sizes =  explode(",", trim($size2->plaintext));`
should be
`$sizes[] =  explode(",", trim($size2->plaintext));`
but it wont work this way..

Comment: can you not add the old line back in and then change the name of the size variable: http://jsfiddle.net/yuL8c11x/6/

Comment: now its echoing fine but storing this text -> **Uploaded**  into sql, it should store 3.74 MiB as its echoing

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yuL8c11x/7/

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of CSS and regex:

```
$desc = $html->find('.detDesc', 0);

if(preg_match('/\d+\.\d{2} [MKG]?B/', $desc->text(), $m)){
  echo $m[0];
}
```